# bootstrap - как сверстать секцию

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: Нужно сверстать такую секцию]

Здравствуйте, подскажите как можно сверстать такую секцию с помощью bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Accusamus aliquam aspernatur eligendi esse est ex laudantium
        magnam minima necessitatibus nemo obcaecati odit officia
        placeat quibusdam quo sint, voluptates. Consequatur, ea.
      </p>
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Accusamus aliquam aspernatur eligendi esse est ex laudantium
        magnam minima necessitatibus nemo obcaecati odit officia
        placeat quibusdam quo sint, voluptates. Consequatur, ea.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="asd" alt="тут будет картинка" height="300" width="250">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Accusamus aliquam aspernatur eligendi esse est ex laudantium
        magnam minima necessitatibus nemo obcaecati odit officia
        placeat quibusdam quo sint, voluptates. Consequatur, ea.
      </p>
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Accusamus aliquam aspernatur eligendi esse est ex laudantium
        magnam minima necessitatibus nemo obcaecati odit officia
        placeat quibusdam quo sint, voluptates. Consequatur, ea.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)